# < becomes &lt; when using strophe.js

Tags: javascript, xml, strophe

I'm sending message containing `<` character.

But the message was recieved as `&lt;` character.

Here's my script:

```
var message = $msg({to: 'user@domain.com', "type": "chat"}).c('body').t('<a href="#">hshshsh</a>').up().c('active', {xmlns: "xhttp://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"});         
Gab.connection.send(message);
```

The message was actually: `<a href="#">hshshsh</a>`

But it was recieved as: `&lt;a href="#"&gt;hshshsh&lt;/a&gt;`

What does make the `<` converted to `&lt;`

Comment: Maybe it is sanitizing the HTML?

Comment: What does HTML sanitizing means? Does it affected by <!DOCTYPE>/meta tag?

Comment: It means the library is transforming normal HTML into sanitized HTML to prevent attacks.

Comment: I've used the strophe.js library in another application and it works fine. It uses the same settings.

Comment: the email client you or the receiver is using is sanitizing the HTML.

Comment: you're correct my library using third party library that sanitized HTML. strophe.js using flensed.js and flxhr.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Possible duplicate:**
>
> [Strophe character encoding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146649/strophe-character-encoding-issue)